# CPP rest sdk json response

Tags: c++, json, cpprest-sdk

I need to parse a JSON response from a CPP rest service.

If the response is Success then the server sends the below response:

```
BODY
{
    "data":{
        "resourceID":"4567890",
        "chunkSize":"10"
    }
    "error": null
}
```

If there is an error then the below JSON is sent

```
{
  "error": {
    "errorCode": "123",
    "errorMessage": "Not able to process the request"
  }
}
```

I tried the code:

```
return client.request(request).then([](http_response response) -> pplx::task<json::value>
{
    std::wostringstream ss;
    ss << L"Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << L"." << std::endl;
    std::wcout << ss.str();
    //return pplx::task_from_result(json::value());
    return response.extract_json();
})
    .then([](pplx::task<json::value> previousTask)
        {
            try
            {
                const json::value& v = previousTask.get();
                // Perform actions here to process the JSON value...
                std::wcout << "Value: " << v.serialize() << endl;



            }
            catch (const http_exception& e)
            {
                // Print error.
                wostringstream ss;
                ss << e.what() << endl;
                wcout << ss.str();
            }


        });
```

However I am not able to parse out each item and get the error code or the required variables in the JSON response.

Comment: Does a `.fail()` give you anything useful?  Is not returning anything in the 2nd `.then()` OK?

Comment: I guess. As long as the output json is parsed correctly.